Maximo PMWOGEN cron not populating asset field for work orders
When Maximo’s PMWOGEN cron finishes, all work orders generated by the cron are missing asset numbers even though the associated PM’s have asset numbers that are in OPERATING status. Please assist and let me know if more detail is needed.
Ran PMWOGEN cron. Generated work orders should have asset numbers since PMs have OPERATING assets, but the asset field is empty for all work orders generated via cron.
